# Multiplicative group of prime order greater than 2

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

For any multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_n$, the order is $\phi(n)$. We know that $\phi(n)$ is always even for $n\ge3$.

Then how can I get a prime order multiplicative group.

Is the order of a multiplicative group means the multiplicatiive order of the generator element in that group?

In Builinear pairing, it is given that $e: \mathbb{G} \times \mathbb{G}_T$ , where both are of same prime order.

Please provide an example for $\mathbb{G}$ and $\mathbb{G}_T$.

Comment: Take the third roots of in the complex numbers.

Comment: Can't we get in integers? @Adelafif I have to do example on it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing two senses of the phrase "multiplicative group". Often that phrase is used to mean *any* group, where the group operation is written using product notation: the identity is written $1$, inverses are written $x^{-1}$, products are written using concatenation $xy$, and powers are written using superscripted exponents like $xx=x^2$.

- One particular kind of multiplicative group is the group of units modulo $n$, written $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^*$. As you note, for $n\geq 3$, the order of this group is even. When discussing this group, one often emphasizes the word *multiplicative* to distinguish it from the additive group $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.
- There are many other groups that are written multiplicatively. These include the multiplicative group of complex numbers $\mathbb C^*$ and its subgroups. As Adelafif notes in the comments, the group of third roots of unity is such a group of order $3$.

When a group is cyclic, yes, its order is the same as the order of any of its generator elements. When a group is not cyclic, it doesn't have a generator element, so of course this doesn't apply.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{Z}_{11}^*$ is a multiplicative group of prime order?

Comment: Nope, the group $(\mathbb Z/11\mathbb Z)^*$ has order $10$, which is not prime.

Comment: So, prime order multiplicative groups of prime order in integers does not  exist? @Chris Culter

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27355/simple-example-to-describe-bilinear-mapping

Comment: You have to be much more explicit about the class of groups you're considering.

Comment: @hanugm: The quadratic residues modulo $11$ form a (multiplicative) subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}_{11}^*$ that has five elements. May be you can use that?

Answer (score -1):

$Z_n$ is not a multiplicative group, inverse does not exist for 0. The order is not \phi(n), please dont get confused, multiplicative group means "a set together with multiplication operation becomes group".for example $U(n)=\{x \in N | x < n$ and $gcd(x,n)=1\}$ is a multiplicative group.

Comment: Your $U(n)$ has order $\phi(n)$, and is commonly also denoted $\mathbb Z_n^\times$ or $\mathbb Z_n^*$, jusr one character away from the OP's incorrect usage.  I don't think this addresses the OP's confusion at all.

Comment: Sorry, i did not come across that notation so far.. Thanks for the tip.